# 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: google-chrome, driver

$ brew install chromedriver
-bash: brew: command not found

I've downloaded the chrome driver and I've even put it in the working directory. Still getting this error. I barely know what python is. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have homebrew installed. The instructions can be found on homebrew's website. https://brew.sh

For connivence, here's the command:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Comment: Bingo! This was it. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?

Comment: Yeah, how do I do that? I tried hitting the up arrow, but it won't count anything from me because I'm so new.

Comment: Take a look here => [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)